# Multiple processes running bash on a ssh server

Tags: bash, ssh, process, operating-system, pid

When I run the "ps" command, I can see all the processes I'm running, but for some reason, there are two identical processes(except for the PID ofc) running bash, I know about the parent and child process, but I think there shouldn't be two identical processes, especially running bash. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

[image: Processes I'm running]

[image: ps -ef | grep "a105448"].com/kf6hN.jpg

Comment: it happens every time you login?

Comment: Yes, I even try to kill the extra process but with no success

Comment: Add output of `ps -ef` so we can see the parent and process IDs.  It could be that you have something in your bashrc or global startup files that causes that.

Comment: @alarmant0 what happens if you run `exit`? do you have to run 2 `exit` to logout?

Comment: @Nic3500 Done, I put grep a105448 because there are a lot of processes running because it's a university ssh server and there are a lot of students.

Comment: @pynexj No, I just need to exit once to logout.

Comment: as in the `ps -ef` output, it's running `bash -c 'cd "/home/a105448"; $SHELL'`. so you have 2 bash instances. seems like your sysadmin configured this for some reason.

Comment: @pynexj Ah ok thanks, but do you know that that command does?

Comment: `bash -c 'cd "/home/a105448"; $SHELL'` -- it just cd's into your home and starts another bash ($SHELL) for you. usually this make no sense because that's the default user login behavior. the server must have some unusual conf. i cannot guess without access to the server but the first thing you can check is your login shell. you can run `getent passwd a105448` for that.